# JavaScript: get words and its indices in a sentence

Tags: javascript

I need to get all the words from a sentence and also their index position within the sentence. The same word can happen multiple times in the sentence.

I was trying to do this using the filter method but the index indicates the position in the array not the position within the sentence.

```
var sentence = "This is a short sentence, a demo sentence."

sentence.split(" ").filter((word, index) => {
    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `map` instead of `filter`, loop the array and find position by calculating the letter count.

> ...and also their index position within the sentence.

By index I assume the position at which the word starts in the sentence.

```js
var sentence = "This is a short sentence, a demo sentence."
let position = 0;
// the words array
const wordsList = sentence.split(" ");

// get the word and position in sentence
const wordDetails = wordsList.map((word, index) => {
  // +1 to account for space
  position = index && wordsList[index - 1].length + position + 1;
  return {
    word,
    position
  };
});

console.log(wordDetails);
```

If you need a different output like `{ <word> : [pos1, pos2] }` try below sample

```js
var sentence = "This is a short sentence, a demo sentence."
let position = 0;
// the words array
const wordsList = sentence.split(" ");
let wordDetails = {};

// get the word and position in sentence
wordsList.forEach((word, index) => {
  // +1 to account for space
  position = index && wordsList[index - 1].length + position + 1;

  // check if entry exists
  if (!wordDetails[word]) {
    wordDetails[word] = [];
  }

  // insert the position in array
  wordDetails[word].push(position)
});

console.log(wordDetails);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `.reduce`:

```js
const sentence = "This is a short sentence, a demo sentence.";
let index = 0;
const nonAlphabeticWithoutSpace = /[^a-zA-Z ]/g;

const res = sentence.split(" ").reduce((acc, item) => {
  // get word without other characters
  const word = item.replace(nonAlphabeticWithoutSpace, "");
  // get prev indices of this word
  const wordIndices = acc[word];
  // create/update the indices list
  acc[word] = wordIndices ? [...wordIndices, index] : [index]; 
  // increment the index
  const nonAlphabetic = item.match(nonAlphabeticWithoutSpace);
  index += nonAlphabetic 
    ? word.length+nonAlphabetic.length+1 
    : word.length+1;
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(res);
```

If you want to disregard case senstivity, use `.toLowerCase()`.

Comment: Thanks it's a nice solution but the other answer was closer to what I was doing.

Answer (score 0):

```js
  // below code will execute an object with key of
  // the index and value 
  
  const sentence = "This is a short sentence, a demo sentence."
        let result = {}
        sentence.split(" ").forEach((word, index) => {
            result = {
                ...result,
                [index]: word
            }
        })
        console.log(result)
        /*
        the result will be like below:
        {
            0: "This"
            2: "a"
            1: "is"
            4: "sentence,"
            3: "short"
            6: "demo"
            5: "a"
            7: "sentence."
        }
        */
```